# how to solve ARRAY OUT OF BOUND EXCEPTION in java

Tags: java, text-files

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class DataDisplay extends JFrame{
    JTable table;
    public static JLabel jl1= new JLabel("Activity ID");
    public static JTextField jt1= new JTextField("Enter Activity ID");

    public static JLabel jl2= new JLabel("Activity name");
    public static JTextField jt2 = new JTextField("Enter Activity name");

    public static JLabel jl3= new JLabel("Start Date");
    public static JTextField jt3= new JTextField("Enter Start Date");

    public static JLabel jl4 = new JLabel("End Date");
    public static JTextField jt4= new JTextField("Enter End Date");

    public static JLabel jl5 = new JLabel("Alarm Before");
    public static JTextField jt5= new JTextField("enter alarm");
    public static JLabel jl= new JLabel("HOURS");


    public static JButton save = new JButton("SAVE");
    public static JButton close = new JButton("CLOSE");
    public Container c= this.getContentPane();

    private static int counter=0;
    DataDisplay(){

        this.setTitle("Assignment 3");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        c.add(jl1);
        c.add(jt1);
        c.add(jl2);
        c.add(jt2);
        c.add(jl3);
        c.add(jt3);
        c.add(jl4);
        c.add(jt4);
        c.add(jl5);
        c.add(jt5);
        c.add(jl);


        jl1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
        jt1.setBounds(100, 45, 100, 30);

        jl2.setBounds(10,60,100,100);
        jt2.setBounds(100,100,120,30);

        jl3.setBounds(10,110,100,100);
        jt3.setBounds(100,145,120,30);

        jl4.setBounds(10,160,100,100);
        jt4.setBounds(100,200,120,30);

        jl5.setBounds(10,210,100,100);
        jt5.setBounds(100,250,120,30);
        jl.setBounds(230,210,100,100);


        c.add(save);
        save.setBounds(10,300,100,30);
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int ce=0;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String tableHeader[] ={"Activity ID", "Activity name", "Start Date", "End Date","Alarm before (Hours)"};
                String tableData[][]= new String[ce=counter+1][10];
                table = new JTable(tableData, tableHeader);

                String line=null;

                BufferedReader b=null;
                try {
                    b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Activity.txt"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                    try {
                        while ((line=b.readLine())!=null){
                            String[] s=null;
                            int row=1;


                            for(int counterc=1; counterc<=5; counterc++ ){//*ARRAY OUT OF BOUND EXCEPTION*
                             s=line.split("|",4);


                            }

                            ***for(int loop=0;loop<=5;loop++){
//here gives exception                              
                                tableData[row++][loop]=s[loop];***

                            }
                            row++;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                tableData[counter][0]=jt1.getText();
                tableData[counter][1]=jt2.getText();
                tableData[counter][2]=jt3.getText();
                tableData[counter][3]=jt4.getText();
                tableData[counter][4]=jt5.getText();


                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                c.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                scrollPane.setBounds(10, 400, 700, 600);
                counter++;
                try{
                    FileWriter out= new FileWriter("Activity.txt",true);
                    BufferedWriter br= new BufferedWriter(out);
                    PrintWriter p= new PrintWriter(br);
                    p.println(jt1.getText()+"|"+jt2.getText()+"|"+jt3.getText()+"|"+jt4.getText()+"|"+jt5.getText());
                    p.close();

                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.getStackTrace();

                }
            }

        });

        c.add(close);
        close.setBounds(200,300,100,30);

        this.setBounds(100,100,1000,1000);
        this.setVisible(true);
        c.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        DataDisplay dd= new DataDisplay();
    }

}
```

Above program displays the table and saves into a file on screen whenever Save button is clicked. When user executes the program again then the last data isn't lost but is displayed on the screen. Data in the file is seperated by "|" operator. So what im trying to do is that loop reads line until end of file and splits it on the basis of pipe operator. And then a for loop displays data on the table. But probelem is my program is giving ARRAY OUT OF BOUND EXCEPTION and I couldn't solve it . So please help!

Comment: Put in some more effort and remove all the irrelevant code. TL;DR - I do not believe all the code you copy & pasted here is related to your issue. We do not have to see all your labels, all your buttons etc.

Comment: The easy solution would probably be to use a list, append to the list and then iterate over it. Right now you're tightly coupled to your data, but if you do something like that it's much more dynamic for changing sets. While you may not need it now, it may serve as a reference in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your `s` array will be no longer than 4 elements. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit *n* is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most *n* - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than *n*, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter...

You set `s` using `s=line.split("|",4);`. Your *n* here is 4, which means the length of `s` is no greater than four.

When you iterate through `s` like this:

```
for(int loop=0;loop<=5;loop++){
    tableData[row++][loop]=s[loop];
}
```

You're trying to access element 5 of a 4 element array. Switch `loop <= 5` to `loop < 5`.

Comment: @user3102085 Are you getting the same error or a different one? Please edit the full error into your original question - that'll help maintain the formatting.

Comment: I've got the same error. But when I deleted the part of code which was giving the error , I got same error in the above for loop(in which string is split)